# How can I make a VF page public?

Tags: visualforce

I came across [this site](https://jeffdouglas-developer-edition.na5.force.com/examples/CustomerSearch) and wanted my own visualforce page to be publicly viewable without any logins. How can I do this?

Thanks
MnZ

Comment: Just FYI, a Guest User license is required in order to have a Guest User profile. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000006778&type=1   If you do not have this license, you won't see Guest User in the list of profiles.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Easy! After creating your Visualforce page:

1. go to Setup > Develop > Sites,
2. register your Force.com subdomain name,
3. create a new Force.com Site
4. next to 'Site Visualforce Pages' click Edit
5. add your page to the list of Enabled Visualforce Pages

Comment: I tried this but as a developer I guess I can't create any more sites nor delete any. Does that mean I need to create another account to try it out ? Anyway I'm accepting your answer.Thanks :)

Comment: Sounds like you already have one set up :-) use that? Or just create another [Developer Edition](http://developer.force.com/join?d=70130000000EjHb) account and drop a new Site in there.

Comment: I added my page to my site. It is saying "Authorization Required

You must first log in or register before accessing this page.
If you have forgotten your password, click Forgot Password to reset it."

Comment: D'oh! Go to Setup > Monitoring > Debug Logs, create one for `Site Guest User` and look for anything interesting. If that doesn't yield and leads, maybe [raise a new question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) showing the source of your Page, Controller and any Extensions.

Comment: custom object permission was required. Solved !

Comment: Nice - good spot!

Comment: @bigassforce awesome answer! Is a domain required? What if I just wanted to create a Public VisualForce page that is tied to a Salesforce object?

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to your site, click on the name and click edit on the "Site Visualforce Pages" section, add the page to the site.